# Create a List<T> using Type object instead of T

Tags: c#, generics

I have an object called LazyLoader<T>.  It connects to an ORM to load the data for the T type when needed.  It works.

LazyLoader<T> inherits from ILazyLoader.

Challenge:  Create a factory class that can load a Generic type from the Object type.

As in,

```
public ILazyLoader CreateLazyLoader(int id, Type typeToLoad)
{
    return new LazyListLoader<typeToLoad>(id);
}
```

Problem: <typeToLoad> does not accept a Type object.  How do I convert the Type <typeToLoad> into something that would work like <T> where T is typeToLoad?

Comment: It should be a generic type argument, not a parameter. `public ILazyLoader CreateLazyLoader<TTypeToLoad>(int id) { return new LazyListLoader<TTypeToLoad>(id); }`

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile time it's a pretty big flag that you shouldn't be using an ORM to begin with.  The vast majority of the features that they offer either require you to know the types you're dealing with at compile time, or fail to provide you with any benefits to not using an ORM if you don't know that information.

Comment: @asawyer: I don't think you can really say that so definitively without any context. While generics are certainly better suited to types known at compile-time, it's far from an uncommon requirement, and in some cases it's justified.

Comment: @Servy The reason I don't know the type, is because this can be inherited.  The lazy loader's objective, is to wait to load an object until it is called on.  In this case, we have a DLL that interacts directly with the database, and the ORM system works great.  But to keep the DB protected, external systems are connecting to this through a web service.  The External dll, uses a different LazyLoader that relies on the WebService to load data, instead of the ORM.   To get this to work, the factory method actually calls a static event that defaults to hidden ORM method, but needs to be overridden

Comment: @WarpWars.Net Then it sounds like you don't actually need this functionality, and would be able to work with generic methods that simply apply constraints to give you enough to work with the items.  It doesn't sound like you need to construct the object based on a `Type` object.

Comment: @asawyer I'm using an event to load to call a method that returns the generic information.  unless I have a different event for every possible data type it will load, I can't use generics directly inside it.  In this case, the same method will load every generic type that will be requested from here.

Comment: @Servy, this could does not work--        
public static delegate ILazyLoader<T> LazyTest<T>();
public static event LazyTest<T> RequestedLazyTest<T>;

Which is what I require, so an external DLL can change out the Lazy Loader as needed.

Comment: I would add that I thought it would be simple to construct at first as well, but when you get down into it events on type of generic types do not work, without casting a specific type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var llType = typeof(LazyListLoader<>).MakeGenericType(typeToLoad);
return (ILazyLoader)Activator.CreateInstance(llType, id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
var unboundType = typeof(LazyListLoader<>);
var boundType = unboundType.MakeGenericType(typeToLoad);
return (ILazyLoader)Activator.CreateInstance(boundType, new[] {id});
```